# SUM the results of a sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

I am trying to sum the results of the following sql code.

```
SELECT users.username, users.cell, users.date, coin_bank.bought_coins
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN coin_bank ON users.username = coin_bank.seller
WHERE users.sponserid = '27'
```

The above code works, I however want to sum the bought_coins which are returning as duplicate.

I have tried sub queries I can't seem to get it right. Any help will be appreciated.

[image: view results]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: That's another `SELECT SUM(bought_coins) FROM users WHERE users.sponsorid = 27 && bought_coins IS NOT NULL`. If `users.sponsorid` is not a number make it a String, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to GROUP BY and then you can SUM the amount,
EvERY column in a query with GROUP BY has to be in the GROUP BY or have a [Aggregation  FUNCTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)

so that mysql knows which date for example to get in this case the last entry date

```
SELECT users.username,
       users.cell,
       MAX(users.date),
       SUM(coin_bank.bought_coins)
FROM users
LEFT JOIN coin_bank ON users.username=coin_bank.seller
WHERE users.sponserid = '27'
GROUP BY users.username,
         users.cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT u.username, SUM(cb.bought_coins)
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     coin_bank cb
     ON u.username = cb.seller
WHERE u.sponserid = '27'
GROUP BY u.username;
```

Comment: this helps but i would like the results to include the NULL results as well (show the total of 0 for rows with NULL coins. currently the query only returns values where there are bought_coins values)

Comment: @CalvinMazanze . . . This should include the `NULL` results.